# How to integrate custom nginx ingress controller with L7 HTTP(S) loadbalancer in GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, load-balancing, nginx-ingress

Installed ngnix ingress controller through helm it automatically created L4 TCP loadbalancer but I want L7 loadbalancer.

Manually created L7 https loadbalancer pointed NEG as backend to it.but getting 502 error .want to know is this a correct approach or there is another approach too.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a this example https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gke-networking-recipes/tree/main/ingress/single-cluster/ingress-nginx

This is not using manually created LoadBalancers but uses GKE Ingress

Answer (score 0):

For Ingress resource you can define the ingress class to be gce, the Ingress Resource uses the Google Cloud GCLB L7 load balancer to serve traffic.

```
annotations: kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce
```

For more information you can refer the Google Cloud [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke)